# Under what conditions can an orientable Riemannian 3-manifold be defined implicitly?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, 3-manifolds, embeddings

Under what conditions can an orientable Riemannian 3-manifold $\Sigma$ be defined implicitly?
What I mean by implicitly is that there exists a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$, such that $\Sigma$ is diffeomorphic to $f^{-1}(0)$, and the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ pulled back to $f^{-1}(0)$ is equal to the metric on $\Sigma$.

Comment: Using the word "implicitly" are you referring to the implicit function theorem, i.e. do you want $0$ to be a regular value of $f$?

Comment: In your setting, one can make the submanifold to consist of regular points of the defining function (since orientable 3-manifolds have trivial tangent bundle).

Comment: Thanks, ThiKu has answered your question provided the Riemann manifold is complete.

Comment: The function $f^2$ is smooth near the manifold $\Sigma$, but it could potentially have some  non-smooth points far from $\Sigma$.   These could be smoothed-away using bump functions.

Comment: For incomplete Riemannian manifolds the answer is negative.

Comment: @RyanBudney If the smoothed function $\tilde{f}$ is used, then $f(x)$ and $\tilde f(x)$ are not necessarily equal, so I don't think $\Sigma=\tilde f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: You want to smooth $f^2$, that way you do not need  to modify the function near $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the Nash embedding theorem every Riemannian manifold $M$ embeds isometrically into some ${\Bbb R}^n$. You may then take $f(x)=dist(x,M)$ for $x\in{\Bbb R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your clever answer, but I edited the question to require that $f$ be smooth. I think the function you described is not smooth if more than one path minimises the distance.

Answer (score 4):

This is too long for a comment.

If you want $0$ to be a regular value of $f$, then this should be possible iff there is a smooth isometric embedding to $R^n$ with trivial normal bundle (for any dimensional manifold). To see that this is necessary, pull back a frame from $TR^{n-3}$ to the normal bundle to give a trivialization.

This will hold for a 3-manifold after crossing with $R^3$ (since the tangent bundle is trivial, the normal bundle in $R^{n+3}$  will be that of $R^n$ ). A tubular neighborhood of the manifold with trivial normal bundle in $R^{n+3}$ will be isomorphic to the unit disk in the normal bundle (for compact M). Take the map to the unit disk in $R^n$ induced by the trivialization and extend smoothly to get a defining function in which 0 is a regular value.

**Remarks:** I think that the argument should work more generally for manifolds with a proper isometric smooth embedding, but the tubular neighborhood might not have uniform radius. In the general dimension case, a manifold will have stably trivial normal bundle iff the tangent bundle is stably trivial (since these add trivially in K-theory).